# jQuery is Slow in responding to events

Tags: javascript, jquery, disqus

I am using jquery scripts in my website(www.authorsandeepmishra.com), but script is taking sometime to respond to events.

I am using disqus script for commenting in the same website, i have made the navigation bar fixed, but commenting section is still moving above the navigation bar which is not meant.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Show us something, your site, your code

Comment: www.authorsandeepmishra.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your "main.css" at the end of the file:

```
div#navigation {z-index: 1;}   // Add this
#disqus_thread {z-index: 0;}   // Add this
```

This should solve your fixed navigation bar issue. As for jQuery taking time to respond, you'll have to provide more details, as to what type of event it is, code etc...

Comment: When i click the image of the book , it takes time to show the next  image int he same place.

Comment: Your back cover image (back_cover_page.jpg) is 780kb in size, it will load slow on slow internet connections. You can compress the image to a lesser size, maybe change image format, but apart from that you can't do anything about the loading time. It'll depend on internet speed...